# SQL - inner join on different criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Just getting confused on basic stuff -

could someone explain me this -

```
select s.name from students s
inner join friends f on f.id = s.id
inner join packages p on p.id = s.id
where p.salary < (select pp.salary from packages pp where pp.id = f.friend_id)
order by (select pp.salary from packages pp where pp.id = f.friend_id) ASC;
```

the salary comparison part - i.e select pp.salary from packages pp where pp.id = f.friend_id should not yield the same salary result? - so how can we compare.

for references, use the below sample tables

table 1- students 
columns - id, name

table 2 - friends (here each id is linked with one friend_id (his best friend))
columns - id , friend_id

table3 - packages
columns - id , salary

Trying to find out the name of the friend whose best friend's salary is more than his salary.

I am confused at understanding this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `where` subquery part is wrong cause the subquery will return multiple record and which can't be used with `<` operator since it's accepts scalar value. Rather change that to a `JOIN` as well like

```
JOIN packages pp ON pp.id = f.friend_id
AND p.salary < pp.salary
```

Change your query to be

```
select s.name from students s
inner join friends f on f.id = s.id
inner join packages p on p.id = s.id
JOIN packages pp ON pp.id = f.friend_id
AND p.salary < pp.salary
order by pp.salary;
```

Comment: that's correct - i just need to understand that how can we compare the salary from initial joins to salary from sub query when both will yield the same results??

Comment: yes bro - ur query is correct but I need to understand the part - p.salary < pp.salary because to me they will give the same result - which is not true.I just need an explanation for that part.

Comment: @Nikhilvyas, no they won't cause of the different join condition on them and thus the salary fetched would be different as well.

Comment: wanted a better explanation , as I know they will not give the same result - just failing to understand as ids remains same in both the case - so is it that the ordering will be different?